# Correct way to extend Bootstrap Modal - lock, unlock

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to extend bootstrap 3 modal window with ability to disable closing it.

I've built this code:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    var oldHide = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.hide;

    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.hide = function (_relatedTarget) {
        if (this.isLocked) return;
        return oldHide.call(this, _relatedTarget);
    };

    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.lock = function (_relatedTarget) {
        this.isLocked = true;
        e = $.Event('lock.bs.modal', {
            relatedTarget: _relatedTarget
        });
        this.$element.trigger(e);
    };

    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.unlock = function (_relatedTarget) {
        this.isLocked = false;
        e = $.Event('unlock.bs.modal', {
            relatedTarget: _relatedTarget
        });
        this.$element.trigger(e);
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/8fCJ6/)

After clicking "lock," you won't be able to close modal until you click "unlock."

It this way of extending bootstrap modal correct? What are potential dangers of doing this?

And how can I make this better?

**EDIT:**

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/8fCJ6/2/) is my final version based on suggestions.

Comment: I get passing in `this` in case someone overwrite `window`, but what pass in `window` and `document` only to assign them to function arguments with the same name? Does that have *any* effect?

Comment: @DavidHarkness - I found template to write extends, so I build my code based on it. Because I wasn't sure if this is correct I post my code here, to get some comments from pros :)

Comment: @DavidHarkness the idea behind doing that kind of thing is that resolving a variable declared in an "inner" scope should be more efficient than resolving one from an "outer" scope, since the innermost scope is checked first, then the one outside that, and so on. Micro optimization at its finest. BTW, I don't think any implementation actually allows `window` to be overwritten.

Comment: @Dagg so I should leave `(jQUery, document, window)` in my code? or is `(jQuery)` fine?

Comment: @Misiu is this all of your code? It never references `window`, `document`, or `undefined`, so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks fine to me, except that you failed declare the `e` variable in the `lock`/`unlock` functions. So it's an automatic global, which isn't good.

With a little bit of cleanup:

```
(function ($) {
  var _original = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.hide;

  function trigger(target, name, relatedTarget) {
    target.trigger($.Event(name, { relatedTarget: relatedTarget }));
  }

  $.extend($.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype, {
    hide: function (_relatedTarget) {
      if (this.isLocked) return;
      return _original.call(this, _relatedTarget);
    },

    lock: function (_relatedTarget) {
      this.isLocked = true;
      trigger(this.$element, 'lock.bs.modal', _relatedTarget);
    },

    unlock: function (_relatedTarget) {
      this.isLocked = false;
      trigger(this.$element, 'unlock.bs.modal', _relatedTarget);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it cleans globals. I didn't saw that problem until I read this answer.

Comment: @Misiu If you find yourself suspecting your code may have issues like implicit globals (or even if you don't), it's always helpful to run your code through a linter like [jslint](http://jslint.org) or [jhint](http://jshint.com) which'll catch such stuff. And thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Flambino did an excellent review, the only nitpick I have is that I would write

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.hide = function (_relatedTarget) {
    if (this.isLocked) return;
    return oldHide.call(this, _relatedTarget);
};
```

as

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.hide = function (_relatedTarget) {
    if (!this.isLocked){
      return oldHide.call(this, _relatedTarget);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for tweaking my code :) but as I wrote below @Flambino's answer I did't realize that I have potential global leaks. His answer cleaned that problem.

Comment: @Misiu No worries, Flambino's review is far more in depth.